# Bootstrap 3.1.0 modal sizing not applied

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

After updating my `bootstrap-sass` gem to `3.1.0` to take advantage of the new sizing options on modals (`.modal-lg` and `.modal-sm`), I've been unable to get the styling to be applied. My code is as follows:

```
<div aria-hidden="false" aria-labeldby="ccModalLabel" class="modal fade in" id="ccModal" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    ...content...
  </div>
</div>
```

Which, as far as I can tell, is nearly identical to [the example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes) in all the attributes that matter:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, upon inspection, the `modal-sm` class isn't been evaluated in my code as it is in the example, leading me to think that maybe it isn't included in the gem somehow, or am I missing something? The modal works in every other way aside the sizing.

Comment: what is the environment where you are trying this code

Comment: Ruby 2.0.0p353, Rails 4.0.2

Comment: development or production ..is it your local system where you are facing this issue or a live website

Comment: Development, still testing to make sure there weren't any breaking changes

Comment: I'm having the same problem - but not using Ruby

Comment: I think the problem isn't related to Rails, but Bootstrap itself. Maybe you should change the title (remove any Rails related tags)

Comment: The problem I had, I was using an `Admin Template` with a `main.css` which overrode the modal width, I tracked the sources in my browser's `Developer Tools` disabled those and saw where I need to change the `main.css` for the standard bootstrap sizes to work properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try latest Bootstrap - version 3.1.1

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)
[Bootstrap SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

Comment: I'm on 3.1.1.0 and still have the same issue OP.

Comment: did you still have the issue?

Answer (score 13):

I cannot simply update my bootstrap because of some breaking changes so what i did was added this to my site.css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-lg{
      width:900px;
  }

  .modal-sm{
      width:300px;
  }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Worked for me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set $modal-lg with the desired width before your import bootstrap:

```
$modal-lg: 900px;
@import "bootsrap";
```

The default is 900px.